# HTTPS, AWS ELB, CloudFront & S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Background: My division of bigcorp.com was sold off and now we are lilcorp.com.  We have a fleet of appliances deployed that will be looking for software updates on https://updates.bigcorp.com/, but since we no longer control bigcorp.com, we need to update our appliances to check https://updates.lilcorp.com.  bigcorp has given us a cert for updates.bigcorp.com and has a DNS CNAME in place that forwards traffic for updates.bigcorp.com to server.lilcorp.com.

I'm trying to config things like this:

```
              HTTPS           HTTPS

Appliance -----------> ELB -----------> CloudFront ----------> S3

                    Cert for             Cert for
                    updates.             updates.
                    bigcorp.             lilcorp.
                      com                  com
```

I've got the following DNS records in place:

- updates.bigcorp.com CNAME to server.lilcorp.com
- server.lilcorp.com CNAME to ELB
- updates.lilcorp.com CNAME to CloudFront.net address

CloudFront is configured to use an S3 bucket as its origin.

Status:  Things work if I hit CloudFront directly, but that doesn't help since the appliances are hitting the updates.bigcorp.com address.

Questions:

- Can an ELB forward to a CloudFront deployment?  I'm not seeing how to make it a "target".
- Do I need to put a web server in the middle of this to handle the redirect/forward?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can an ELB forward to a CloudFront deployment? I'm not seeing how to make it a "target".

No it cannot. The target (for ALB) can be only an private IP address, lambda and instance id.

> Do I need to put a web server in the middle of this to handle the redirect/forward?

Yes, you would need some kind of proxy. With ALB, you could use lambda function. So ALB would invoke a lambda function, and the function would query external CloudFront distro and return the results.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into the Lambda solution, but for now, my workaround is to simply use DNS to alias updates.lilcorp.com to the CloudFront host.